# What do I do with this [x-post] question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, questions

I initially posted a question SO

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934982/opening-yoast-com-opens-up-my-localhost-dev-server

[But it was being flagged as off-topic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uhgZ.png)

[So I posted it here on SF.](https://serverfault.com/questions/540740/whats-causing-this-site-to-redirect-to-my-localhost)

1. Was I not supposed to do that?
2. Is this question even off-topic for SF? (it's being downvoted)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cross-posting is generally frowned upon when your question is *open* on one site, since the community there sometimes will migrate it to another site. In this case cross-posting just creates duplicates that someone has to come and deal with. If the question is *closed* as off-topic, though, it can be re-posted on a more appropriate site.

Unfortunately, Server Fault doesn't appear to be the appropriate site, as it doesn't appear to have anything to do with professional system or network administration.

I've migrated your question to Super User, where you should be able to get an answer.

Comment: It should be noted that migrations from [SO] to [SF] seem to have been disabled entirely, so not even moderators are able to do a migration. In this special case, the question has been *closed* on [SO] with the specific reason that it would be on-topic on ServerFault. So we had the migrations disabled but now they're pointing fingers at us and encouraging people to cross-post.

Comment: @syneticon-dj [SO] moderators can still migrate things here, as far as I know. [Their _3K+ community_, however, cannot](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3853/126632), which is probably where their custom off-topic message came from.

Comment: @syneticon-dj Yes, SO moderators can still migrate things here, as evidenced by the inbound migration page in the 10k tools: http://serverfault.com/tools?tab=migrated&daterange=

Comment: Oh, I see. So they probably rejected my flags requesting question migration out of lazyness. I have read the reason "migration target has been removed" twice and assumed they were *really* unable to do it.