# Should the "Ask Question" process warn that we require a professional context?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions

Recently, there was a popular Meta question concerning [changing the site subtitle](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3800/changing-the-site-subtitle) to prevent inbound migrations of off-topic questions.

The old site subtitle was:

> Q&A for system administrators and desktop support professionals

The site subtitle recently changed to:

> Q&A for professional system and network administrators

We continue to receive off-topic questions that are asked directly at ServerFault. When asking a new question, users are told only that their question should relate to "servers, networking, or desktop infrastructure." For the majority of users who do not read the FAQ, there is *no indication whatsoever* that questions will be rejected if they do not relate to these topics in a *professional* capacity.

We are wasting our time, not to mention that of countless naive askers, because the "Ask Question" user experience practically *invites* off-topic questions relating to home networking and home workstations.

Should we change the "Ask a question" title hint and sidebar to specify "in a professional capacity"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are right, that is one area that the scope is not defined. Well, the **very critical distinction** of our scope, at any rate. I believe you are correct, that the wording in the Ask a Question side-bar:

[image: Ask a Question, just one in-scope please]

Be adjusted appropriately:

> Is your question in a professional context, and relating to servers, networking, or related infrastructure?

The drop of 'desktop' is intentional as a minority of such questions that get asked here are *actually* topical. It is by far the most subtle thing in our scope to explain, and one that just can't be done in 15 words or less; especially 15 words that have to explain other topics as well.

Comment: I kinda think that the sort of people who will read that are the sort of people who don't need to read it, if you see what I mean. We certainly should try our best to help them, though.

Comment: @RobM The theory here is that **people will read the bold text**, even with just a glance, so getting that '**professional**' word in there may cause enough doubt in the edge cases to cut down our OT-rate. It may not be a lot, but it'll help.

Comment: Oh I get that, I totally agree with doing it. I'm just saying, lets not over-estimate how much effect it will have on the 'post and run' brigade.

Comment: Suggested addition, similar to the "ask it on meta" blurb (if feasible): "If your question is about personal computing, [ask it on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) instead."

Comment: Any chance that "read the faq" could be in bright red, blinking and 72 point? "FAQ" should also be capitalised.

Comment: Note that this text appears in two places on the Ask Question page, so I tweaked your suggestion slightly.

Comment: Completely agree with this. We need to emphasize that this site is for professionals.